# I am trying to convert the following visual basic code into c# code

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the following visual basic code which is from a windows forms application into c# code in web forms:

This is the Visual Basic code:

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
   

_availebletimeSlotsRoom1 = New BindingList(Of String)(_allTimeSlots.ToList)
_availebletimeSlotsRoom2 = New BindingList(Of String)(_allTimeSlots.ToList)
_availebletimeSlotsRoom3 = New BindingList(Of String)(_allTimeSlots.ToList)
_availebletimeSlotsRoom4 = New BindingList(Of String)(_allTimeSlots.ToList)

    UpdateRoom(1, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom1)
    UpdateRoom(2, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom2)
    UpdateRoom(3, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom3)
    UpdateRoom(4, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom4)
```

End Sub

This is the C# code I have tried:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    _availebletimeSlotsRoom1 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList);   //ERROR HERE      
    _availebletimeSlotsRoom2 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList);        
    _availebletimeSlotsRoom3 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList);        
    _availebletimeSlotsRoom4 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList);

  
    // ERROR HERE:   
    // 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Start' and no 
    // extension method 'Start' accepting a first argument of type                                                                                                                      
    // 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
    // an assembly reference?)
    UpdateRoom(1, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom1);                           
    UpdateRoom(2, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom2);
    UpdateRoom(3, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom3);
    UpdateRoom(4, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom4);
}
```

Comment: So does it work? If not, why not? Please spend some more time on your question.

Comment: But I can see you are missing parentheses: `.ToList()`

Comment: The only thing I see syntactically is that you need `()` after `ToList`. VB does not require parentheses if you do not pass any parameters.

Comment: In vb you have `DateRangeEventArgs`. In c# you only have `EventArgs`. That's why `Start` is not defined on e.

Comment: What would the alternative be for DateRangeEventArgs in C# for start to be defined

Comment: Looks like you're using a different component between the two examples, or at least different events. Use the same component and the same event and you'll have the same arguments, whether you're using VB or C#.

Comment: I've down-voted the question because it appears to have been changed so much that the comments no longer make sense. Kayla,when you edit your question, please provide updates rather than completely change the content, otherwise the question and comments become nonesensical to later readers.

Comment: In c# can cast the sender parameter to the type of component you are using. If this is some sort of calendar component, maybe you can get what you want that way.

Comment: You have put the code in the wrong event handler though, the old code uses the `DateSelected` event and the new one is `SelectionChanged`. Fix that.

Comment: @M.G , What would the alternative argument be for DateRangeEventArgs in C# web forms for start to be defined as I am using the visual studio web forms calendar control

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what you have already changed based on the answers you got. So in your current code are still multiple problems:

1. as mentioned by @DavidG you need to use parentheses on `_allTimeSlots.ToList()`
2. In vb you are using the event `DateSelected` which gives you `DateRangeEventArgs` in c# you are using the `SelectionChanged` event which only gives you `EventArgs`. So I think you have chosen the wrong event to put your code in. And thats also the reason why you have those errormessages.